# recursive function in model doesnt return anything - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I made a function inside `category` model :

```
   public function getSecondCategoryByID($category_id = 0,$id = 0)
    {

        $category = $this->where('id','=',$category_id)->first();

        if($category->parent_cat_id == 1)
        {

            $mcategory = $this->where('id','=',$id)->first();


            echo 'Inside Model '.$mcategory->id;
            return $mcategory->id;


        }else{
            $this->getSecondCategoryByID($category->parent_cat_id,$category->id);
        }

    }
```

at a function of controller I called this function :

```
    $category = new Category;

    $secondCategoryID = $category->getSecondCategoryByID($category_brand->category_id,0);

    echo 'After Model   '.$secondCategoryID ;
    return ;
```

when I call my function of controller I got this message on page :

```
Inside Model 3After Model //it should be  Inside Model 3After Model '3'
```

I think my model  doesn't return anything ! because after `after model` is nothing !!!!!

Comment: You forgot about RETURN in ELSE block

Comment: Are you trying to make parent-child recursive relation within the same table?

Comment: @nospor if block  is end of recursive processes .

Comment: But ELSE also need to return value... `return  $this->getSecondCategoryByID($category->parent_cat_id,$category->id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing recursion you need to return the recursive call also, here shown by changing the else block statement.

```
else
{
    return $this->getSecondCategoryByID($category->parent_cat_id,$category->id);
}
```

Comment: What's great about this answer is that it works for ajax calls to Laravel controllers. Before trying this, in my controller, I was calling my recursive method and not returning anything, which returned a blank string to ajax.